# ChatGPT banner is polluting search results

Tags: bug, status-review, user-experience, google, seo

The text of the banner is the first thing shown in some of Google's search result previews. It's easy to make this show up by explicitly including `chatgpt` in your search query - e.g. searching for [`failed to open stream permission denied "chatgpt" site:stackoverflow.com`](https://www.google.com/search?q=failed+to+open+stream+permission+denied+%22chatgpt%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com) - but it's also happened in other circumstances, as shown below.

[image: Google search preview that says "Mar 31, 2017 — We do not currently allow content pasted from ChatGPT on Stack Overflow; read our policy here. failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/ ..."]

Maybe moving the HTML down to the bottom of the page would be warranted, unless it's going away soon.

Comment: *Surely* this is a feature, and not a bug.

Comment: We *really* want people to know not to post ChatGPT answers on Stack Overflow

Comment: if only that worked!

Comment: Does anyone know if this has happened before with previous alert banners?

Comment: @blackgreen [Streisand effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect) suggests that it's more likely to work the other way 'round

Comment: ah yes: 'we fully support usage of ChatGPT on stack overflow'

Comment: @Makyen I just checked what I think is the same search and it's not there now. Maybe after seeing it enough times, Google's crawler realized it is part of the site navigation and stripped it out?

Comment: It still seems worth keeping in mind for future banners though.

Comment: @miken32 That's possible. I initially tried the searches shortly after you posted this question and didn't see the banner at that time. I figured I'd try again later, but still don't see the banner in a search. Hmmmm... Actually, if I include the term "ChatGPT" in the search, then I can see 1 out of 100. So, if I [*require* "ChatGPT"](https://www.google.com/search?q=failed+to+open+stream+permission+denied+"chatgpt"+site%3Astackoverflow.com), then I can see such results. I should have tried that when I first tested.

Comment: Using [the (new) link](https://www.google.com/search?q=failed+to+open+stream+permission+denied+%22chatgpt%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com), I see it on every search engine hit on Google (logged out), but not [on DuckDuckGo](https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=failed%20to%20open%20stream%20permission%20denied%20%22chatgpt%22%20site%3Astackoverflow.com) (the JavaScript-free version).

Comment: This also [happens with the HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304034/323179), but it's not as obnoxious because it's under the question content.